# Dynamic Row height in GridView.builder (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

[image]

I'm trying to use a `GridView.builder` with dynamic height depending on the largest item in each row. A `Wrap` is not ok for this, because it renders all items at once. the builder is only rendering the visible items. I won't calculate a `childAspectRatio` manually for each row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a `WrapBuilder` which sort of like a `Wrap` but uses a builder. The caveat though is that you need to know the width of the items beforehand. If that's okay you can try using this class:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

typedef ValueWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(T value);

class WrapBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemWidth;
  final List items;
  final ValueWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;

  const WrapBuilder(
      {Key? key,
      required this.itemWidth,
      required this.items,
      required this.itemBuilder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      var itemsPerRow = max(1, constraints.maxWidth ~/ itemWidth);
      return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: ScrollController(),
            itemCount: (items.length / itemsPerRow).ceil(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var rowItems = items.sublist(itemsPerRow * index,
                  min(itemsPerRow * (index + 1), items.length));
              return Row(children: [
                for (final item in rowItems)
                  SizedBox(
                      width: itemWidth,
                      child: itemBuilder(item))
              ]);
            },
          );
    });
  }
}
```

You might need to tweak it for your use case. In my case I have a list that is some data and the `itemBuilder` takes one of this data as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

you can pass height as variable in list and then set height for the row from list