3000 or 5000 items in wrap cause a lot of time to render the ui in flutter
From this question Flutter: How to use Wrap instead of ListView.builder? , I am creating a wrap widget like this. It work well but using 100ms to render the ui.
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    for (var i in _items)
      Text('Item $i'),
    // spacer to make last line space between
    const Spacer(),
    const Spacer(),
  ],
)

reduce the items to render , <=1000 it work well, however if 3000 or 5000 take too much time to render.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

The problem with Wrap is that it doesn't lazy load like a ListView.builder would. Meaning it builds all of its children, even the ones not in view. You could try this WrapBuilder I came up with, although that one only works with fixed width children: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360444/1514861

@lvo thanks , I am using GridView.builder now , it's performane is well.

Finally I am using GridView.builder to build my widget , it has no problem in performance.
